# How to use multiple entry in where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, where-clause

I have ninety customer order REFNOs and want to include all of them in WHERE clause.

I have written this:

```
select * 
from  TO_SALES_INVO 
where REFNO = '201582255'
```

The above will return me one record. But now I have list of REFNO (20190525,2018525, etc) and want to select all of them using SQL. The REF No is not in any sequence or range and they are random. Nevertheless I want the result **in the same order I put in WHERE clause**. For example : `where REFNO in ( '12','2',' '5','1')` should order the same way as in the parentheses.

How to do it?

Note : I am using Toad

Comment: You say you're using TOAD. But that's a developer tool. What tool will your users' use to run this query? Where do the REFNOs come form? How are they stored?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM TO_SALES_INVO WHERE REFNO IN (201582255, 20190525, 2018525)
```

Note: if `REFNO`'s datatype is numeric, then don't surround the values with single quotes.

Comment: this is helpful.. but i want the result the same sequence i put in where clause ... example : where REFNO in ( '12','2',' '5','1') should order the same way as in the Parentheses

Comment: @Bodhi: without an `ORDER BY` clause, result sets are not ordered - the database is free to return the data in whatever order it finds convenient. If you want to have data returned in a particular order you have to use an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: The IN operator is useful if there are few records involved, but if the number of records is high, for performance reason the JOIN is more suitable.

Comment: @Bodhi - if the order of the result set is important to you you should include that requirement **in your question**. That way you only have to type it once instead of commenting on every answer you get, plus responders know there's a specific (and tricksome) requirement they have to address.

Answer (score 2):

If they're not in a sequence or range, then you can list them out in an IN condition.

```
select * from  TO_SALES_INVO 
where REFNO in ('201582255', '20190525', '2018525', ...)
```

If you can get just the reference numbers that you want in a query, then you can use that as a subquery instead of listing them all out.

```
select * from  TO_SALES_INVO 
where REFNO in (select REFNO from ...)
```

Comment: this is helpful.. but i want  the result the same sequence i put in where clause ... example  :  where REFNO in ( '12','2',' '5','1') should order the same way as in the  Parentheses

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the table ORDER with REFNO field, you can try with the query:

```
SELECT * from ORDER WHERE REFNO in (SELECT REFNO FROM TO_SALES_INVO);
```

Better choice with explicit JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER t1 JOIN TO_SALES_INVO t2 on t1.REFNO=t2.REFNO;
```

In general I suggest to adopt the explicit `JOIN`, because has a lot of performance advantage in general than the `IN` (i.e. prefer the second type of query instead of the second type of query).

Comment: I was typing my reply when your answer came in.  For this many values, load them into a table and join to it!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you have all REFNO which you can pass to sql IN clause like,

```
select * from  TO_SALES_INVO 
where REFNO IN ('201582255', '20190525', '2018525', ...)
```

Comment: this is helpful.. but i want it order the result the same sequence i put in where clause ... example : where REFNO in ( '12','2',' '5','1') should order the same way as in the Parentheses

Comment: @Bodhi In SQL you order results using [`order by`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Sorting-Query-Results.html).

Comment: Yes you can use order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (select '12' as REFNO FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      select '2' FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      ....
     ) A
JOIN TO_SALES_INVO ON ...
```

Please notice that you must use UNION ALL instead of UNION or there will be a grouping performed in sub query "A" which will change the order.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the results that you want, even though the syntax for the list of REFNO values is a bit different (i.e. comma separated string).  It generates a set of rows for the items that you're filtering by and then joins to that.

It uses a technique to split the comma separated value as found [here](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/).

```
WITH
    DATA AS (SELECT '12,2,5,1' str FROM DUAL),
    LOOKUP AS
    (
        SELECT LEVEL lvl, REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) str FROM DATA
        CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT TO_SALES_INFO.*
  FROM LOOKUP INNER JOIN TO_SALES_INFO ON LOOKUP.str = TO_SALES_INFO.REFNO
  ORDER BY LOOKUP.lvl;
```

If your list of REFNO values is going to be reused it is probably best to just create a separate table for them rather than using the complex CONNECT BY stuff that I've shown.